# Change form url query parameter with jquery on input change state

Tags: javascript, jquery

Trying to create an "add to cart" button with quantity of items to add, i've added an `<input id="product_quantity" value="1" onChange="updateQuantity()" />` to a main `form` so whenever i change a value inside that `input` it should update a form's action url withing a query parameter to corresponding value from `input` field.

Here is the overview in HTML:

```
<form action="index.php?option=com_virtuemart&view=cart&task=add&virtuemart_product_id[]=1&virtuemart_category_id[]=1&quantity[]=1&format=json">
    <input type="product_quantity" value="1" onChange="updateQuantity();"/>
    <input type="submit" />
</form>
```

So how to change a form's action url parameter string `&quantity[]=XXX` to a specific value which is typed in `input`'s field ?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of putting the quantity on the URL as a GET parameter and trying to update it with javascript, just put a `name=quantity` attribute on the input field and it will get posted with the form. In general, since you're posting a form you probably want to send data as POST parameters instead of get. It looks like you're using PHP, so you can access your post vars using `$_POST["quantity"]` in your PHP script.

```
<form action="index.php?option=com_virtuemart&view=cart&task=add&virtuemart_product_id[]=1&virtuemart_category_id[]=1&format=json">
    <input type="text" name="quantity" value="1" onChange="updateQuantity();"/>
    <input type="submit" />
</form>
```

I would probably put the other GET params in hidden fields on the form too.

Answer (score 1):

```
$('#product_quantity').change(function () {

    var quantity = $(this).val();
    var form_url = $("form").attr("action");

    form_url.replace('quantity[]=1', 'quantity[]=' + quantity)

    //submit the form
    $("form").submit();
});
```